# Не видит название кнопки

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть кнопки с названиями Button_Edit и Button_Delete. Но в коде выводит ошибку "не существует в текущем контексте".

```
<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="LV_Goals" Background="#202020" BorderBrush="#202020" SelectionChanged="LV_Goals_SelectionChanged">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" Width="310" Height="25">
                    
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Grid Height="20">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProjectName}" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid x:Name="Grid_Buttons" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" MouseEnter="Grid_Buttons_MouseEnter">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                            <Button x:Name="Button_Edit" Height="25" Width="25" BorderThickness="0">
                                <Image Source="/Resources/Edit.png"></Image>
                            </Button>

                            <Button x:Name="Button_Delete" Height="25" Width="25" BorderThickness="0">
                                <Image Source="/Resources/Remove.png"></Image>
                            </Button>

                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```